# Displaying a new value from array after X time

Tags: php

This is a loading page problem in PHP7.1 + Apache2. I have a set of messages which are in an array. Currently, while loading the page any random message is picked up and displayed.

Following is the PHP code used for random array message:

```
$randomMessage = array (
    'Message 1',
    'Message 2',
    'Message 3',
    'Message 4',
    'Message 5',
    'Message 6',
    'Message 7',
    'Message 8',
    'Message 9'
);
$data ['text_page_loading'] = $randomMessage[rand(0, count($randomMessage) - 1)];
```

The problem is the page take a while on slower connections to load.

Is it possible to have a new message from the array to be displayed after every X seconds.

Comment: Yes, if you use JavaScript.

Comment: How do you output the message?

Comment: Note, while your way of choosing a random array value _works_, it would probably be better to use the function meant for this, e.g `$randomMessage[array_rand($randomMessage)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make php file `message.php` from where you provide message. And in that file

`message.php`

```
<?php
$randomMessage = array (
    'Message 1',
    'Message 2',
    'Message 3',
    'Message 4',
    'Message 5',
    'Message 6',
    'Message 7',
    'Message 8',
    'Message 9'
);
$data ['text_page_loading'] = $randomMessage[rand(0, count($randomMessage) - 1)]; 
echo json_encode($data);
```

in html where do you want to print message add `id = "msg"`

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

in script first import the jquery library and

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'message.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
         var response = JSON.parse(data);
         $('#msg').html(response.text_page_loading);

        },
        cache: false
      });
    }, 5000);  // after five second it will hit the server process response
});
</script>
```